# Seeking efficient algortithm finding common sequences in numeric arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, compare

I'm seeking an efficient algorithm to locate common sequences in *n* arrays.
The arrays have the following features:

- Array items are integer numbers
- The number of items expected in each array is several thousands
- Numbers may vary in range significantly, like more than 2^32
- Items are expected to be ordered with a high probability, like 95%
- Items are expected to consist of multiple *runs* of varying lengths, i.e.: number *x* is followed by *x+1*, followed by *x+2*, ...
- The total number of items (*m*) in each array is expected to be the same in many cases

The algorithm should be able to

- Determine the (number of) common items for each pair of arrays, maybe all the rest, also
- Determine the (number of) unique items as compared to all the other arrays
- Determine the ratio of unique to common items in respect to all the others
- The algorithm should be preferably more efficient than O(*n* * *m*^2)

Initially I was thinking about converting each array to a bitmap, and then doing boolean operations on those, but considering that the size could be larger than 2^32 bits, it will probably consume too much RAM (more than 260 MB per bitmap).

As the first three goals are somewhat equivalent, having only the ration would be fine, too.

Comment: Consider compressing the runs as pairs (starting-value, length). Finding the common sequence between two compressed pairs is easy.

Comment: As you will have at least an output per pair of arrays, and there are O(n²) pairs, the contribution of *n* in the complexity will be at least n², so I don't understand where you are getting O(n m²) from.

Comment: I guessed comparing two arrays of size *m* is O(*m*^2), so when having *n* arrays it's O(*n* * *m*^2).